# Jquery count items between 2 elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML tree like this

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
</div>
```

I have a click function that runs everytime an image within a div class item is selected, is there anyway I can count the number of divs with a class of item are next to each other.

ie, if I clicked on '1' in my example above, it would return 2, because there are 2 divs before the h1, if I clicked on item 7, it would return 5 etc

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: if it is possible to add one more element before item class as parent after every <h1> tag so it will be easy for you.

Comment: you can take parent node as object to count number div in parent node

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
$('.item').on('click',function(){
    var h1 = $(this);
    while(!h1.is('h1')) h1 = h1.prev();
    alert(h1.nextUntil('h1').length);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eJJ99/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.item').click(function () {
        alert($(this).prevAll('h1').first().nextUntil('h1').length);

});
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/UZPLx/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can count all your siblings which have the class `item`:

```
var count = $(this).siblings('.item').andSelf().length;
```

(In jQ 1.8 and later you're supposed to use `addBack()` not `andSelf()`)

The jQuery API reference is very helpful, recommended reading:

- http://api.jquery.com/siblings/
- http://api.jquery.com/addBack/

and most of all, the two big lists of selecting and traversing methods:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
- http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: This would word if you wrapped all of your `.item` div's in another div

Comment: Good point! I misread the structure. My answer is wrong. Adil's answer using index() is then a better way (although it's not checking that the divs have class item, if that matters)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look through the pages you suggested, this was helpful

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.item').click(function(){

            var title = $(this).prevAll('h1').first();
            var nextElement = title;
            var reachedNextTitle = false;
            var noOfDiv = 0;
            var loopLimit = 1000;
            var count = 0;
            while(!reachedNextTitle){
                count ++;
                nextElement = nextElement.next();
                if(nextElement.is('h1')){
                    reachedNextTitle = true;
                }

                if(nextElement.is('div')){
                    noOfDiv ++;
                }
                if(count > loopLimit){
                    break;
                }
            }

            alert(noOfDiv);
        });
    });
```