# Count how many items fall between another element Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

I have a list that looks something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item play">1</div>
  <div class="item do-not-play">2</div>
  <div class="item play">3</div>
  <div class="item play">4</div>
  <div class="item do-not-play">5</div>
  <div class="item do-not-play">6</div>
  <div class="item play">7</div>
</div>
```

How would I count how many items with the class `do-not-play` fall between each `play` item?

For example, if I were to click on item 1, it would count how many `do-not-play`'s it finds until it gets to item 3, which would return 1.

Or if I clicked on item 4, it would return 2 `do-not-play`'s.

My question is similar to this question:
[Jquery count items between 2 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967481/jquery-count-items-between-2-elements) but their issue is slightly different. I don't have h1 tags separating my list items, only play and do-not-play items.

How would I make this possible? Thank you.

Here's an answer from the other post that seems like I could get it working for my issue.

```
    $('.play').click(function () {
        alert($(this).first().nextUntil('play').length);
    });
```

Comment: 2 questions.  1) Can you post what you have tried so far so we can help you fix it, and 2) What do you think should happen if you click item 5?

Comment: 1) I've literally only attempted to use some of the answers in the similar question I posted above, trying to manipulate some of those answers into something that will work. 2) Nothing will happen when clicking on do-not-play items. Only clicking play items will do something.

Comment: I edited my post to include as far as ive gotten with one of the answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
nextUntil('play')
```

You are looking for a class so change the previous line with:

```
nextUntil('.play')
```

```js
$('.item').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).nextUntil('.play').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="item play">1</div>
    <div class="item do-not-play">2</div>
    <div class="item play">3</div>
    <div class="item play">4</div>
    <div class="item do-not-play">5</div>
    <div class="item do-not-play">6</div>
    <div class="item play">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, such a simple mistake. This works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach to avoid looping in every click

```js
$(function() {
  var $lastPlayItem = "";
  var lastPlayIndex = -1;
  var $item = "";
  var $playButtons = $(".container .play");

  $.each($playButtons, function(i, item) {
    $item = $(item);
    if (i === 0) {
      lastPlayIndex = $item.index();
      $lastPlayItem = $item;
    }

    if ($item.index() > lastPlayIndex + 1) {
      $lastPlayItem.attr("data-count", $item.index() - lastPlayIndex - 1);

    }

    lastPlayIndex = $item.index();
    $lastPlayItem = $item;

  });

  $playButtons.click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("data-count") || 0);
  });
})
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
}

.item.play:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item do-not-play">2</div>
  <div class="item play">-1 Play</div>
  <div class="item do-not-play">2</div>
  <div class="item play">1 Play</div>
  <div class="item do-not-play">2</div>
  <div class="item play">3 Play</div>
  <div class="item play">4 Play</div>
  <div class="item do-not-play">5</div>
  <div class="item do-not-play">6</div>
  <div class="item play">7 Play</div>
</div>
```